# app.get() cannot find and show the right template(jade) page

Tags: node.js, express, templates, server, pug

I am studying about very basic Serverside JS using express, jade, node.JS.

At the first page (localhost/topic), there is a list. And List's data from MySQL. 
(MySQL fields are id, title, description, and author)
Also, there is a link to open the form (the form is in add.jade file) that can add an item on the list.

My problem is that if I clicked the link, the page still shows the view.jade. But, the address is changed to "localhost/topic/add".

I've checked the "app.js" file to see if app.get() isn't set appropriately. But I did not find any.
Actually, the template was written as jade at first. But I tried to convert jade to pug. After this error, I put them back all to jade.
Is that a problem?

Thank you.

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set("views", "./views_mysql");
app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Connected, 3000 port!");
});

app.locals.pretty = true;

var mysql = require("mysql");
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "jimin",
  password: "****",
  database: "o2"
});
conn.connect();

app.get(["/topic", "/topic/:id"], function(req, res) {
  var sql = "SELECT id, title FROM topic";
  conn.query(sql, function(err, topics, fields) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    if (id) {
      var sql = "SELECT * FROM topic WHERE id=?";
      conn.query(sql, [id], function(err, id_topics, fields) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
        } else {
          res.render("view", { topics: topics, topic: id_topics[0] });
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.render("view", { topics: topics });
    }
  });
});

app.get("/topic/add", function(req, res) {
  var sql = "SELECT id, title FROM topic";
  conn.query(sql, function(err, topics, fields) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    } else {
      res.render("add", { topics: topics });
    }
  });
});

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
// add.jade

doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
  body
    h1
      a(href='/topic') Server Side JavaScript
    ul
      each topic in topics
        li
          a(href='/topic/' + topic.id)= topic.title
    article
      form(action='/topic/add' method='post')
        p
          input(type='text' name='title' placeholder='title')
        p
          textarea(name='description' placeholder='description')
        p
          input(type='text' name='author' placeholder='author')
        p
          input(type='submit')
```

```html
//view.jade

doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
  body
    h1
      a(href='/topic') Server Side JavaScript
    ul
      each topic in topics
        li
          a(href='/topic/' + topic.id)= topic.title
    article
      if topic
        h2= topic.title
        = topic.description
        div= 'by ' + topic.author
      else
        h2 Welcome
        | This is Server Side JS Tutorial
    div
      a(href='/topic/add') add Topic
```

```
app.get("/topic/add", function(req, res) {
    var sql = "SELECT id, title FROM topic";
    conn.query(sql, function(err, topics, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
        } else {
            res.render("add", { topics: topics });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the arrangement of the routes.

**TLDR**

Move the route definition of `app.get` above the previously declared route.

**Explanation**

Route definitions in express are from a top-to-bottom approach. So, in runtime, your routes are seen as follows:

- `/topic`
- `/topic/:id`
- `topic/add`

When you visit the page `/topic/add`, you would expect it to match to the third on the list but Express actually matches it to the second on the list... It will actually match **everything** if you put anything after `/topic`.